# Convert "for" loop to "foreach" loop for multi array

Tags: php

Here's my array:

```
$applications = array(
    array(
        "title" => "AB",
        "server" => array("Domain")
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "BC",
        "server" => array("Domain", "Admin", "Server 1", "Server 2", "Server 3")
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "DE",
        "server" => array("Domain", "Admin", "Server 1", "Server 2")
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "FG",
        "server" => array("Domain", "Admin", "Server 1", "Server 2", "Server 3")
    ),
);


for ($i=0; $i<count($applications); $i++){
    echo $applications[$i]["title"] . "<br>";
    for ($j=0; $j<count($applications[$i]["server"]); $j++){
        echo $applications[$i]["server"][$j] . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The for loop works great.  Can I do the same using foreach loop cause I find it looks cleaner?  If so, how do I go about converting this for loop to a foreach loop?

tks

Comment: Have you tried it yourself yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it like this:

```
   foreach ($applications as $app) {
        echo $app["title"]."<br>";
        foreach ($app["server"] as  $server){
            echo  $server."<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Or

```
   foreach ($applications as $app) {
        echo $app["title"]."<br>";
        echo implode("<br>", $app["server"]);
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Check the manual for [Implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php). the code becomes much cleaner.

Comment: This is great.  Thank you